# How to make a single line bold in a RichEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-6, richedit

How can I get one specific line to be bold in a RichEdit?

Comment: Set `SelAttributes` and write a new line. Or, select an already existing line and set `SelAttributes`.

Answer (score 6):

Formatting in a rich edit control is done like this:

1. Select the text to which formatting is to be applied.
2. Apply that formatting to the selection.

It goes something like this:

```
RichEdit1.SelStart := SelectionStart;
RichEdit1.SelLength := SelectionLength;
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style + [fsBold];
```

Of course, you have to work out what to use in place of `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength`. Ultimately that comes down to how you are managing the text and I don't think there's enough information in the question to give you a single definitive answer on that topic.